# Jenkins blue ocean can not save pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-blueocean

the tomcat server shows the below execeptions.
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: E-mail address of PersonIdent must not be null.

Answer (score 0):

In the account that you are working on the pipeline, click the username on the top right hand corner of Jenkins, it will then bring you to the profile page. Then go in and update the email.